# Ubuntu not using 61gb free space

Tags: partitioning, format, micro-sd

I formatted an SDHC card using win32 disk imager all working, booting up etc but when I go to look at my free space I only have 20mb of free space. I open up disk manger and there two unallocated partitions, one 20mb an another 61gb how do I get Ubuntu to using the bigger, 61gb instead of 20mb?

This is a geniune 64gb SanDisk Ultra A1. I can confirm it is 100% genuine, and `df -h | grep -i /dev` shows:

```
udev            416M     0  416M   0% /dev
/dev/mmcblk0p2  2.7G  2.5G   54M  98% /
tmpfs           484M   43M  441M   9% /dev/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   50M   17M   33M  35% /boot
```

Comment: Are you saying that you erroneously installed Ubuntu to the wrong partition? Or are you saying something else? It's not clear.

Comment: No I'm saying I installed everything correctly but when I go to file viewer it says I only have 21 mb of free space when it's a 64gb card.

Comment: Done put the code in. @K7AAY

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu, its Ubiquity installer defaults installation to the first partition. Instead, choose **Something Else** as shown in the [official installation tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5), and make sure the installation of the OS goes to /dev/mmcblk0p2 instead.